# Why doesn't model.predict() work well on novel MNIST-like input?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, mnist

I'm an experienced developer, new to Machine Learning.  I'm experimenting with Keras/TensorFlow, starting with the mnist_mlp.py example.  I installed Keras and TensorFlow using pip on a Mac.

In order to understand the inner workings better, instead of running the file ('python mnist_mlp.py'), I'm cutting and pasting the file contents into a Python (2.7.12) interactive window.

Everything runs fine and I get the 98.4% test accuracy as noted in the comments of that file.

What I want to do next is to feed it novel input and use `model.predict()` to see how it performs.  I create 28x28 images in GIMP and bring them into my Python session (being careful to convert from 4-channel, 8-bit RGBA images to a linear single-channel floating-point array).

When I feed this into the model, I get what look like strange results to me.  Some images are correctly categorized while others are wildly off.
They look like perfectly reasonable numbers to me, and they match the MNIST set examples pretty closely.  When I extract the array back out and look at it it looks OK, so it doesn't seem to be a flipping or flopping issue.  When I feed MNIST images in the same way, they appear to work correctly.

I'm not sure what's going on here.  Is it a case of overfitting?  Why is the validation data set the same as the test set?

Test images and python code with instructions can be found here:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/stackoverflow-47799896/StackOverflow_47799896.zip

Thanks.

EDIT: I tried the same test with the convnet example (mnist_cnn.py) and got slightly better results but still similar errors.  If anyone wants to try that, they can use the same functions in the readme.py file but make these changes:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.ndarray((1,28,28,1), dtype='float32')

def l (s):
    with open(s, 'rb') as fd:
        _ = fd.read(1)
        for i in xrange(28):
            for j in xrange(28):
                v = ord(fd.read(1))
                x[0][i][j][0] = v / 255.0
                _ = fd.read(3)
```

EDIT 2: Interestingly, if I replace the first 19 items in the training data set (out of 60,000) with my images in the MLP case, I get at or near perfect prediction of all my images after training.  Does this suggest overfitting?

Comment: Do you have any plotter that you can call from python? Such as `matplotlib` for instance. It would be nice to check in this plotter if your images do appear to be like the MNIST ones (From the same plotter). Also, check your maximum and minimum values. MNIST usually goes from 0 to 1, are your images in this range? (Check that the range is the same between your and MNIST images)

Comment: I believe https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate place to ask those kind of questions.

Comment: Yes, the way I am bringing the images into python they end up as floating-point in [0,1].  They are visually similar to the images in MNIST; whether they are statistically different in some way that's confusing the NN I don't know.  I edited the OP to include a link to my test files.

Comment: Maybe this would be better asked on datascience.stackexchange.com but as I am new to ML I am assuming that I'm making some kind of basic mistake with Keras or perhaps TensorFlow.